# What is the significance of a URI suffix?

Tags: html, uri

I created a file and named it as test.txt. The file contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
Testing ...
</body>
```

When I point a browser to it, the content of the file is not rendered. If I renamed the file to test.htm, it gets displayed correctly, i.e., w/o the markup symbols. Would someone please explain the significance of the suffix, or point me some documentation regarding that? Thank you.

Comment: Your OS associates various extensions with various MIME types, each one representing a different content type.  A `.txt` extension is probably associated with `text/plain`.

Comment: Technically, file extensions have no meaning in the HTTP protocol.

However, all browsers seem to be using some file extensions to automatically guess the content type when no content type is sent. ( I'm aware of txt, htm, html) (Maybe on OS leven as @Mike suggests, I don't know) Not sure whether a central documentation of this behaviour exists

Comment: Oh for some reason I was thinking this file was opened locally.  But yes, the HTTP header `content-type` can always override this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a file system, the file extension is to determine what type of data is stored in a file.

In an HTTP URI, it is meaningless … however if you are mapping URLs onto a file system (the usual method of serving static content) then the web server will use the file extension to determine the `Content-Type` HTTP response header which is used by the browser to determine the type of data.

Comment: Quentin, thank you. I thought the suffix in an HTTP URI _is_ relevant in general. For instance, .php, pl suffix will trigger some form of script processing by the server. I may have misunderstood your point; I'm trying to understand/learn more here.

Comment: A server might be configured to treat a file with that extension as a program to be executed, but usually due to its filename on the file system rather then the URL.

Comment: This doesn't match my experience 100% - I'm pretty sure *browsers* do content-type overriding too, when no content type header is sent. Random example from the interwebs: http://www.textfiles.com/anarchy/FREELOADING/atms.txt doesn't seem to be sending a `content-type` header but is treated by the browser as `text/plain`

Comment: @Pekka웃 — I see a Content-Type header there. (Some browsers do perform content type sniffing, but that's edge case error recovery).

Comment: @Quentin indeed - I can see it in Safari; I'm not sure why Chrome is deciding to hide it from me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqFyn.png but that's another matter

Comment: @Pekka웃 — It's a Not Modified response, not an OK response. There isn't any content in the response, so there is no content-type for it.